# Fragment components are null on orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments

My game profile activity receives an intent with an id passed in and with that id I then request from my firebase database the game which has the id, and only when the game is found I set its info inside a fragment.

Here's how I request and then add pass the _Game object to my fragment (code omitted for brevity, normally I have all ChildEventListener methodes added in)

```
    public void findGameById(final int id) {
    mGamesRef.orderByChild("id")
            .equalTo(id)
            .limitToFirst(1)
            .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    _Game game = dataSnapshot.getValue(_Game.class);
                    mGameInfoFragment.setGameInfo(game);
                }
            });
}
```

And of course the id passed as parameter is the id gotten from the intent. `findGameById(int id)` is called in the activity's OnCreate

My `GameInfoFragment` in where the `setGameInfo(_Game game)` resides

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game_info, container, false);
    String dateFormat = SharedPrefManager.read(SharedPrefManager.KEY_PREF_REGION, getString(R.string.default_date_format));
    mDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    mTodayTimeMillis = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    // Summary UI
    mTextSummary = view.findViewById(R.id.summary);
    mReadMore = view.findViewById(R.id.read_more);
    mSummaryLoading = view.findViewById(R.id.summary_loading);
}

    public void setGameInfo(_Game game) {
    // Stop/hide all ongoing progress bars (loading)
    mSummaryLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}
```

All is good until I change my orientation, because then on orientation change it gives me this following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ProgressBar.setVisibility(int)' on a null object
>   reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android framework destroys the fragment and recreates it on configuration change by default. If you did not handle the configuration change yourself, then your fragment have been recreated. This reference to the fragment

```
mGameInfoFragment.setGameInfo(game);
```

may not be valid anymore hence the NullPointerException. As a rule of thumb, do not store references to objects with lifecycle such as activity and fragments, as they are volatile and can cause memory leak (yours is an example of memory leak, the system cannot free your old fragment since you still have a reference to it).

One approach is to handle orientation change yourself. Read further [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes)

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Another approach is to make sure that you always get the fragment that was inflated and shown by the framework before invoking the methods.

Comment: Thank you for the help my friend, the link you provided is very informative!

Comment: I forgot to mark your answer as the accepted one. Sorry for the delay, please have a nice day ^^